# My c++ code for summing up the array elements does't work right

Tags: c++

I have written some code to add all elements of an array and display the result, but it does not work right, what's possibly going wrong?

I tried it with 2-5 elements, but the only one giving correct result is the one with 2 elements.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, sum=0;
    int arr[n]; \\no of array elements
    cout<<"enter the number of array elements\n";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"enter the array elements\n";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];    \\got my array filled
    }
    cout<<"calculating the sum...\n";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sum=arr[i]+arr[i-1];
    }
    cout<<"the answer is:\n"<<sum;    \\i think the problem is in this loop
    return 0;
}
```

for a 3 elements array, if the input is 1,2,3; then the result is 5. Probably the code is excluding the first element

Comment: `int n; int arr[n];` this is undefined behaviour

Comment: It's also not grammatically correct C++.

Comment: Variable length arrays are not standard C++. If you do choose to use them you need to make sure the variable you're using for the length is actually initialized at the point of the array declaration. You can't make the array then change the size variable later and expect it to change anything.

Comment: Unrelated: When writing a title for a question, try to make it descriptive and helpful to those who follow and can learn from your question. Suggestion: Don't include stuff like *doesn't work right* because that's implied. If the code worked right you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: Use `std::vector` for _dynamically sized_ arrays.

Comment: Use it right (with `push_back` or `emplace_back`) and you don't even have to know ahead of time how many items are coming (but it's often faster if you know ahead of time and can `reserve` space).

Comment: Sidenote: If the program's output is to sum inputs, as in the array is not used for anything other than the summation, you can skip over the storing of the inputs in the array and simply sum them as they come in. Save a lot of code and processing time.

Comment: One liner -- `#include <numeric> ... std::cout << "The answer is " << std::accumulate(arr, arr + n, 0) << "\n";` -- Isn't C++ great?

Comment: What does ``\\ `` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem 1:

```
int n, sum=0;
int arr[n]; //no of array elements
```

you want to initial array by n. But this n is undefined.
so, you can write it

```
int n, sum=0;
cout<<"enter the number of array elements\n";
cin>>n;
int arr[n]; //no of array elements
```

problem 2:

```
sum=arr[i]+arr[i-1];
```

in each iteration, you have added just current array value and the previous array value. Also your code want to access arr[-1] address. :D

so, you can write it

```
sum=arr[i]+sum;
```

in each iteration arr[i] add with the previous total sum.

Comment: You do know that the comment introducer in C++ is `//`, not \\?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth Actually, I copied from the given code. Thanks for your correction.

Comment: i am sorry thats my bad... i actually dont comment my code, it was just for putting an explanation there...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the for.
You are for some reason subtracting `arr[i]` and `arr[i-1]` and adding it to sum?

2 elements work because if you take `i = 1`, i - 1 = 0. So you are summing up `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` which are all elements of the array.

If you want to SUM ALL elements in the array just do `sum += arr[i];` (in the adding for).

Also you are setting sum to `arr[i]-arr[i-1]` and not summing it up.